# How does indexing work in google app datastore if entity have unindexed data earlier?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a table in `ndb datatstore`. In that I have

```
updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=False)
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=False)
```

With this structure I have many records in the table. Now I am updating the unindexed fields `indexed=True`. So, will it index all `updated` and `created` data present till date in that table or it will start indexing data to be filled in after indexing ?

And how do I index the unindexed rows of these columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties will not be indexed on existing entities, until you rewrite them with the index enabled. This is because indexes are set at a per entity level.

To ensure you index all these fields, you'll need to read every entity then write it back down. For smaller datasets, you do go this with a simple query and loop. For larger datasets you will want to explore something like Cloud Dataflow.

If you have a large dataset and concerns on costs, you could do some optimizations. For example, do a keys-only query against the indexed fields, then if any read entity matches that list, don't write it back (since it's already indexed).

Comment: Thanks ! We have 6.3 million of rows in that table currently. We have recently shifted from old system to GAE. For moving data from old system, the process we followed is:
`read json -> put each record as task -> create entry in table` async. What do you think would be best ?

Comment: @Dan McGrath -  - is backup and a restore an option in this case? The documentation on this page states - "Note that the backup does not contain any indexes. When you restore, the required indexes are automatically rebuilt using the index definitions you uploaded with your application."

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla no, the backup will tag the entities in question as 'noindex', so restoring will not change that fact. Remember, property index settings are per entity, not per kind (aka ~table) as you might think.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @DanMcGrath!